# XML to JSON Conversion using STAXON

Tags: java, json, xml

XML to JSON Conversion using STAXON. Can this conversion would be datatype specific, meaning keeping a JSD(Json Specific Definition) and let the converter know the datatypes to convert in to JSON. Is this possible? Main problem while converting from XML to JSON is datatype mismatch, so is there any possibility the conversation can happen by keeping JSD (Json Schema Definition) as base?

There is a property in STAXON as autoPrimitive which can make it as true or false. when it is "*true*", the conversion is clever enough to identify the numbers and strings and if it "*false*" conversion is always string.

Problem I see here is if autoPromitive as "*true*", general behavior of the conversion is like a string beginning with ‘0’ followed by several other digits, is not a number. Otherwise it considered as a number.

If we need the conversion based on the schema define, how can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance.